# Unable to add two ajax web parts on same page

Tags: 2010, development, web-part, visual-studio

I created two similar visual web parts (one lists top 10 "popular-content" items, another top 10 "new content" items) with ajax support. For querying data from list (in both wparts) I use similar linq query. Both web parts work OK if I put them separately on different pages, but if I put them on same page I got error

**"Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))"**

Problem: Web parts work separately OK but together they won't (first wp added to page work, but adding second generates error).

Please any suggestion?

p.s. Update panels have different names, also as timer controls which are used to enable ajax functionality (I assume this shouldn't be a problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you disposing of an SPWeb or SPSite obtained from the current SPContext in your logic?

Comment: both web parts have their own logic defined as shown below     
**using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
{ 
linq query;
gridview binding;
}**

Comment: "Well there's your problem". If you dispose of the Context, it's not available at all again until the page is reloaded. Use `new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)` instead.

Comment: only if you create your objects yourself, do you get to dispose them. Read this guidance from MSDN to clarify http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: James - You were right. After modification,everything seems ok. Thank you!!!
@Anders - Thanx, I will read guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with James Love and don't dispose of the current context's spweb and spsite objects.  But you might also run into this another problem with multiple update panels on the page.  Did you implement anything to handle this?

I had to use Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() in javasript and check if an update was already in progress and if so, queue the update panel request until the first one returns. I used code similar to the code below to fix this issue.

```
var _callQueue = new Array(); 
var _executingElement = null; 
var _prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
_prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);
_prm.add_endRequest(endRequest); 
function initializeRequest(sender, args) { if (_executingElement != null) { var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement(); if (_executingElement != postBackElement.id) { args.set_cancel(true); Array.enqueue(_callQueue, postBackElement.id); } } }
function endRequest(sender, args) { _executingElement = null; while (_callQueue.length > 0) { var elements = Array.dequeue(_callQueue); var webpart = document.getElementById(elements[1]); if (webpart != null) { var progress = document.getElementById(elements[2]); if (progress != null && progress.style != null) { progress.style.display = 'none'; } if (webpart != null && webpart.style != null) { webpart.style.display = 'block'; } } else { _executingElement = elements[0]; setTimeout("__doPostBack('" + _executingElement + "', '')",0); return; } } }
```

Comment: I also use PageRequestManager. But for now I don't have any problems with update panels. All are async, and it seems that everything is ok (I have scriptmanager defined in master page, maybe that is a difference between our web parts)

Comment: Ok, good.  I also have script manager on the master.  This was a few years go for SP 2007 so maybe something has changed.  Thanks!